# Logistic Regression - Finding out information about a particular $X_i$ when all other Xs and parameters are known

Tags: logistic

Suppose someone made the following logistic regression:

$Logit(p)$ = $\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2$

Now, someone else is trying to replicate the model creation, but by mistake the $X_2$ column is replaced by some other values. Hence, the model is coming as:

$Logit(p)$ = $\beta_0^{'} + \beta_1^{'}X_1 + \beta_2^{'}X_2^{'}$

I know all the values of the Xs and the parameters in the two equations except the values of $X_2$

My question is: How can I get back the values of $X_2$? I know that getting the value of $X_2$ for each row may be a challenge. Can I get something at an aggregated level at least (mean, sum, etc.)?

Comment: Do you have any distributional assumptions for $X_2$ that you are willing to make? For example normal, log normal?

Comment: $X_2$ is simply a column in a real life data. Assuming a distribution of it will not be practical I guess

Comment: The fact that $X_2$ is a column in a real life data seems to go against you not knowing $X_2$?

Comment: No no. My issue is the actual column $X_2$ got replaced with something else by mistake. Now I am trying to get some info about the original $X_2$ column

Comment: Do you know what the variable $X_2$ measures ... blood pressure, income etc. ? And do you know the population of the original data set including $X_2$?

Comment: It is actually a proportion variable that has only 3 distinct values (0.31, 0.49 and 0.84) across the entire data. And yes, the population for both the models are the same, hence that info is available.

Answer (score 1):

I would use model fitting to assess the likelihood of x2 being a specific value within a given range:

Let’s say that there are 3 samples (i=3)
Every sample is 0.31, 0.49 or 0.84
Distribution of x = average of all the unique x combinations ([0.31, 0.31, 0.31], [0.31, 0.31, 0.49] etc until max of [0.84, 0.84, 0.84])

For each possible value of x, compare the output of the regression to the original regression function ()  and calculate the loglikelihood (which is basically asking what are the odds that that’s the right value of the lost x)

Assumptions:
I’m assuming you have the output of the original () calculation And that the data of x was not replaced by random noise and thus ’2 is similar to 2.